# No provider for MdDialogRef

Tags: angular, mddialog

I reoponed this issue since it didn't solve my problem in a similar discusion.

I still have the error **'No provider for MdDialogRef**' even after i followed the official tutorial step by step.

I have two components. First component :

```typescript
import { MdDialog} from "@angular/material";

import { DocumentDialogComponent } from './document-dialog.component';    

@Component({
  selector: 'documents-list',
  template
})
export class DocumentsListComponent {

  constructor(
     public dialog: MdDialog) {
  }

  openFormDialog() {

   let dialogRef  = this.dialog.open(DocumentDialogComponent,
   {
   }
   );
   dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.selectedOption = result;
   });
  }
```

My second component (The Dialog) :

```typescript
import { MdDialogRef} from "@angular/material";

@Component({
 selector: 'document-dialog',
 template
 })

export class DocumentDialogComponent {
    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DocumentDialogComponent>
    ) {}
}
```

And my module config :

```typescript
  import { MaterialModule } from "@angular/material";
  import { DocumentsListComponent } from './documents-list.component';
  import { DocumentDialogComponent } from './document-dialog.component';

  imports : [
    MaterialModule.forRoot() 
   ],

  declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      DocumentListComponent,
      DocumentDialogComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [
      AppComponent,
      DocumentListComponent,
      DocumentDialogComponent
    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    bootstrap: [
      AppComponent
    ]
```

Why i still have the error :

```typescript
Error in ./DocumentsListComponent class DocumentsListComponent - inline template:0:167 caused by: No provider for MdDialogRef!
```

Comment: Where are you importing `MaterialModule`?

Comment: In the imports section. I updated my question

Comment: Have you tried importing `MaterialModule` instead of `MaterialModule.forRoot()`?

Comment: This works here https://plnkr.co/edit/KLCVS6

Comment: Do you import `DocumentDialogComponent` in `DocumentsListComponent`?

Comment: Yes i do. The import It's in the DocumentListComponent

Comment: Is the `DocumentDialogComponent` decorated with `@Component(…)`?

Comment: Yes it is. See my post

Comment: @WilliamLohan. The plunk works fine but not on my side. It can be related to the version of the angular/material ? cause i dont understand why it's not working and i keep have the same error ! i Have the 2.0.0-beta.2 verison

Comment: @Kivo I don't think so I used @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.2 locally before making the plunker. My steps were `ng new [proj-name]`, `cd [proj-name]`, `npm install @angular/material`, copy/paste your code.

Comment: So i have no idea what is the problem then !!

Comment: Grrr, so frustrating to waist 2 days to find out what is the problem. When i use html inside my the component template it Works !!

Answer (score 4):

I removed the `<DocumentsListComponent></DocumentsListComponent>` tag inside my template and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

We can eliminate this error by setting reference in *DocumentDialogComponent* using  **componentInstance** property.

Rather than injecting the MdDialogRef in to the component we can set its property by componentInstance of returned reference from open method.

Here is the modified working code:

```
import { MdDialog} from "@angular/material";

import { DocumentDialogComponent } from './document-dialog.component';    

@Component({
  selector: 'documents-list',
  template
})
export class DocumentsListComponent {

  constructor(
     public dialog: MdDialog) {
  }

  openFormDialog() {

   let dialogRef  = this.dialog.open(DocumentDialogComponent);

    //set the reference here
    dialogRef.componentInstance.dRef = dialogRef;

   dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.selectedOption = result;
   });
  }
```

The dialog component is here:

```
import { MdDialogRef} from "@angular/material";

@Component({
 selector: 'document-dialog',
 template
 })

export class DocumentDialogComponent {
    public dRef:MdDialogRef<DocumentDialogComponent>
    constructor() {}
}
```